# Merge two files based on pattern

Tags: linux, awk

I would like to merge few files based on first column

```
    File 1: 
    1
    10
    100
    1000
    1001
    10013
    10018
    1002

    File 2:
    100     TRUE
    1001    TRUE
    1041    TRUE
    1099    TRUE
    1213    TRUE
    1227    TRUE

    In this case the output would be:
    1
    10
    100      TRUE
    1000
    1001     TRUE
    10013
    10018
    1002
```

The "non-matching" lines could be left blank or with "FALSE". Also True and False can be changed for values if its easier!

I tried the join command and a couple of awk commands found in other posts but nothing works so far. I have 17 files to join so I was looking for something easy :)

Any ideas on how to get me started?

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: is file2 a lookup file used to mark other files? you should probably use a scripting language like python - bash would be too ugly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you know the linux "join" command:

```
$ join -a 1 f1 f2
1
10
100 TRUE
1000
1001 TRUE
10013
10018
1002
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey I think I managed to do it (with a messy awk command), in case someone needs it here is the line:

```
    awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]=$0;next}{a[$1]=$0}END{for (i in a) print a[i]}' file1 file2
```

Yeah happy me!